# Using IF ELSE in SQL recordset

Tags: php, html, mysql

So here's my code for the dynamic table in **Dreamweaver**

```
SELECT diagnose.Service_id, 
IF (diagnose.Type_id = '1',('บันทึกระบบกระดูกและกล้ามเนื้อ'), ('บันทึกแล้ว')) as Diagnose
FROM diagnose
```

So the problem is how do I use the `ELSE IF` option if the `diagnose.Type_id = 2` and so on?

Comment: What use CASE instead?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, you should have this information in a reference table.  I would expect the code to look more like:

```
SELECT d.Service_id, t.type as diagnoses_type
FROM diagnose d JOIN
     Types t
     ON d.Type_id = t.Type_id;
```

If you don't have such a reference table, you should build one.

Comment: Do you mean the Type table?

Comment: @JoshuaJohn . . . Yes.  `Types` (in this example) would be the reference table for types.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CASE`  for this, see [MySQL on CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html):

```
SELECT diagnose.Service_id,
    (CASE diagnose.Type_id 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'lorum'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'ipsum'
    END) as Diagnose 
FROM diagnose
```

An alternative notation for CASE, that gives you more freedom, is:

```
SELECT diagnose.Service_id,
    (CASE  
        WHEN diagnose.Type_id=1 THEN 'lorum'
        WHEN diagnose.Type_id=2 THEN 'ipsum'
    END) as Diagnose 
FROM diagnose
```

Comment: Is this possible? (CASE diagnose.Type_id 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'lorum','saved'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'ipsum','saved'
    END) as Diagnose 
FROM diagnose

Comment: You can in any case not assign 2 values to a single column, as `Diagnose` will be a column after all. So then you could either make it a single string with some delimeter that you in further processing split, or you do this twice.

Comment: can i use two CASE in one statement?

Comment: Yeah sure: `CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END as Diagnose, CASE WHEN 2=1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END as Saved`.

Comment: ahhh i see but how will i make the word change for example each of the type id will direct to a different submit page because of the types for example 'CASE              
WHEN diagnose.Type_id=1 then 'save' ELSE '-' END' type 1 refers to nervous system submit page which is the nervous table and is a foreign key to the diagnose table

Comment: You really really should do that in a reference table and refer to the ids for each row.